# error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask

I get `FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2` in my `doInBackground`: Don't take into account `String... urlActus` because I have deleted for this post

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... urlActus) {         

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }
} 

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }

}

private static String DB_NAME = "externalDB";
DB_PATH="/data/data"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/";


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{


    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); //EROR LINE

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

I don't uderstand why during `doInBackground` when I try to build -> `OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);`

It's my LogCat Output :

```
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400): Caused by: java.lang.Error: Error copying database
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at com.example.savingfiles.DatabaseHelper.createDataBase(DatabaseHelper.java:67)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at com.example.savingfiles.SplashActivity$Traitement.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:81)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at com.example.savingfiles.SplashActivity$Traitement.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:1)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-22 14:51:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(8400):     ... 5 more
```

I have this exception, what solution can I do to avoid this?

Comment: don use "this" in background

Comment: does your class extend SQLiteOpenHelper if so use activityname.this.getWritableDatabase()

Comment: Yes my class extend SQLiteOpenHelper  SplashActivity.this.getWritableDatabase(); : don't work because this method is undefined in SplashActivity (where there are my method doInBackground)

Comment: is your database in asset folder?? because you try to open it like this: InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); myContext.getAssets() is for access to your asset folder project.

Comment: Yes my database is in my asset folder with the good name.

Comment: Yes, my BDD project works solo and when I put in my thread he doesn't works alone, but I have a problem when I put this in my AsyncTask project

Comment: @Pierre_S: suggestion: try to close your database before a copy because when you call this.getWritableDatabase() method, your database is still opened. try dbExist.close();

Comment: dbExist is a boolean, i tried this.close beteween this.getReadableDatabase(); and copyDataBase(); and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps your problem could be as simple as the fact that your filename appears to be constructed incorrectly:

```
DB_PATH="/data/data"+context.getPackageName()+"/databases/";
```

It appears that you are missing a slash between "data" and your package name:

```
DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
```

But actually, one step better would be to not hard code the path at all.  Instead, use this:

```
DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases/";
```

You can check out [my blog post](http://scottweber.com/2013/02/28/avoiding-file-problems-on-multi-user-devices/) on why it is important to do it this way instead of hard coding the path.

One final suggestion would be, in your `catch` block, do not clobber the original `IOException` that you are catching.  If you want to add some context, that is fine.  But instead of just `throw new Error("Error copying database.")` which is quite difficult to debug, try `throw new IOException("Error copying database.", e)` which will pass along the original exception as well, making it far easier to debug.

Comment: At the first I thought it's the problem but when I put : DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";  I have this outuput in my LogCat /data/data//databases/externalDB I tried your solution but I have  Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.francebtp/com.example.savingfiles.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It is not correct context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() return "data/data/your_package_context/files" SO BE CAREFULL.

Comment: @Pierre_S my guess is that you are trying to use `context` before it has been initialized.  Make sure your code is an an appropriate location where `context` is valid and not null.

Comment: @Jarvis if you hard code the path then your app will fail on devices with multiple users when more than one of them have your app installed.

Comment: public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  this.myContext = context;
  DB_PATH = myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases/";
 }   @Jarvis it's not a good initialize ?

Comment: @Pierre_S: The result of this : myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() is "data/data/your_package_context/files" so it does not correspond to "data/data/your_package_context/databases

Comment: I try to put DB_PATH="/data/data/com.example.savingfiles/files/"; in hard because myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() for my mind, is empty, I don't know why, because I initialized my context

Comment: @Pierre_S: I dont want my email visible on this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the value of `outFileName` (logging or debugging) and you will see it is incorrect.

Another recomendation is to not hide the original exception. You are capturing an IOException, which has the real information about the error, and then you are not passing it to the Error class, so you loose any information on the real reason of the failure (FileNotFound, permission problem ...)

Just use this :

```
       try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database",e);
        }
```

and the original exception will be logged as a nested exception allowing you to see the actual problem.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, this is my LogCat Output ; 05-22 15:30:25.408: E/AndroidRuntime(9551): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 15:30:25.408: E/AndroidRuntime(9551): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.francebtp/com.example.savingfiles.SplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Don't understand, it is different than the one posted in the question?. Using context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() as suggested in another answer should be the way to go.

Comment: Yes it's different but the fatal exception start at the first, none of my logcat test appear